# ng2-file-upload is not working with angular 6

Tags: angular

I am wroking with ng2-file-upload package in angular 6.
I had my backend in PHP.

I am able to select file but when I try to click on upload getting this error:

```
Failed to load [api url]: Response to preflight request doesn't pass
access control check: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' 
header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's 
credentials mode is 'include'. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is 
therefore not allowed access. The credentials mode of requests 
initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials 
attribute.
```

Added Header to my API

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin','http://localhost:4200/');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
```

Still have the same problem.

Thanks.

Comment: header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin','*');

Comment: @Exterminator not working :(

Comment: `header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");` my bad, use this

Comment: both not working.

Comment: post your front end and back end code

Comment: @prashantfepale Did you solve this problem? Did you find any information about this? I have the same problem - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53014285/i-have-been-trying-to-find-an-answer-for-two-months-http-localhost4200-is-n

Answer (score 0):

You can add these instead of what you are using

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token , Authorization');
header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 1728000');
```

preflight `option` request is rejected as you are not allowing that method.